# How to create an Export Plugin for Confluence

Tags: plugins, export, confluence

I'd like to create a plugin that exports into a custom document format similar to the way that export to PDF and export to Word currently work in Confluence.

Does anyone have experience creating a custom export plugin for Confluence?  If so do you know of any resources or samples that describe what would be involved?

Comment: For anyone else looking into doing this, I would recommend looking at the Auto Export plugin source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the most useful resources that I've found so far:

- [Plugin Tutorial - Adding a custom action to Confluence](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Adding+a+Custom+Action+to+Confluence) - This shows how to add an action to the "Tools" menu that appears at the top of a confluence page.  Additionally it shows how to interact with the Page object to get more info about the page.
- [Plugin Module Types](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/PLUGINFRAMEWORK/Plugin+Module+Types) - The second guide I found helpful was the list of general plugin module types.  It was informative to discover that a "plugin" is really a collection of "modules" and seeing this list was helpful to understand how to apply that model to creating a plugin of the type I was looking for.  Additionally the [Confluence Plugin Guide](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Confluence+Plugin+Guide) was also helpful for a breakdown on Confluence specific plugin modules.
- [The Confluence Developer FAQ](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONF30/Confluence+Developer+FAQ) - Useful for information on how to convert wiki content from a page into HTML as well as a number of other hard-to-find gems.

Finally, it was hard to find, but in order to understand how to "target" a particular menu or area of the existing UI to extend, I found it very helpful to read about the guide for [Creating your Plugin Descriptor](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Creating+your+Plugin+Descriptor).